# django template form shows the result in another html file

Tags: python, html, django

I want my search result to be displayed in another html file. I have my template as follows:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            {% for i in var1 %}
                {{i.name}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <form action="searchresult.html" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="search1">
            <input type="submit" id="click1" value="search">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### views.py

```
def search(request):
    var = ""
    if request.method=='POST':
        s1  = request.POST.get("search1")
        var = form1.objects.all().filter(keyskills=s1)
    return render(request,"search.html",{'var1':var})
```

#### models.py

```
class form1(models.Model):
    name          = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyskills     = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name,self.qualification,self.keyskills
```

My result shows search details in the same page. instead I want it to be displayed in `searchresult.html`. I have written the `searchresult.html` in action of form tag. Please give me your suggestion.

Comment: templates with html extension and pages defined in views and urls are different things . what is there in urls and views ??? u haven,t mentioned that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the `action` attribute of your form to the URL that is mapped to the `search` method.
2. In your `search` method; return the `searchresult.html` template: `return render(request, 'searchresult.html', {'var1': var1 })`.
3. In the `searchresult.html` template, add:

   ```
   {% for i in var1 %}
       {{i.name}}<br>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like form Action repesents the Html file, rather than django method to be invoked.

What you do fundamentally is this:

1) You have a form with POST operation, and while submitting, the method that you mentioned in the 'action' tag will get invoked.

2) Once you process with POST datas, then redirect to searchresult.html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to

```
<form action="{% url your_project_name.your_app_name.views.search %}" method="post">
```

It would help if you posted your urls.py content.